# Activity won't start a service

Tags: android, service, android-activity

I m trying to start an IntentService from the main activity of y application and it won't start. I have the service in the manifest file. Here's the code:

MainActivity

```
public class Home extends Activity {
    private LinearLayout kontejner;
    IntentFilter intentFilter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        kontejner = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.kontejner);
        intentFilter = new IntentFilter();

        startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), HomeService.class));
    }
}
```

Service:

```
public class HomeService extends IntentService {

    public HomeService() {
        super("HomeService");
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "TEST", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.salefinder"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Home"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_home" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".HomeService" />
    </application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
</manifest>
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: Both an Activity and an IntentService have valid Contexts, what happens if you replace` getBaseContext()` with `this`?

Comment: Nothing, just a blank white screen

Comment: I started a Toast from `onHandleIntent()` just fine, but since an IntentService stops as soon as it completes its task, the Toast's handler was destroyed and leaked the Toast. It wouldn't good away until I manually cleared the app from cached memory... _Oops._ So I suggest using a Log statements as well. But I don't see any reason why you should see a LogCat statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seams that android cached a bad version of the app - I forced closed it and started it again, and it worked...

Answer (score 1):

`onHandleIntent` gets called from a background thread. You can't modify the UI, or in this case, make Toast from outside the UI thread.  So, I wouldn't expect anything to happen with your service.

Just try writing something out with `Log.d()` to see if your service is getting called.